# Swift - How to get an unknown number of asynchronous operations to execute one after the other (synchronously)?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue

I have a set of asynchronous operations of an unknown amount that need to executed one after another because they are updating the same resource. At the end of all the executions, I want a single point of completion to be notified that they're all complete.

e.g. I have a basket that has an unknown number of eggs in it (`numEggs`). I need to call `api.removeEgg(eggID:fromBasket:completion:)` for `numEggs` times - but i don't want the subsequent egg to be removed until the previous egg is completely removed, as they cannot modify the basket at the same time. When all of the eggs are removed, the client code should be notified once.

Which is the best mechanism to achieve this given the amount of tasks is unknown? I've attempted to use `DispatchGroup`, but it seems the asynchronous tasks are kicked off at the same time. `OperationQueue` would work the same way.

NOTE: This is *not* a duplicate of this question: [Calling asynchronous tasks one after the other in Swift (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34007257/calling-asynchronous-tasks-one-after-the-other-in-swift-ios)

The difference is that I *do not know* the number of asynchronous tasks that need to be completed one-after-the-other. In the referenced post, the type of the tasks are known at compile time and can simply be chained - I don't know until runtime how many asynchronous tasks I'll need to execute.

Comment: *I have a set of asynchronous operations of an unknown amount that need to executed one after another because they are updating the same resource.* That's pretty much the definition of synchronous tasks -- you need to wait for one to finish before you start the next.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't know if there's a second task until the first task has completed, and you don't know if there's a third task until the second task has completed, and so on?

Comment: no, i know how many tasks there are before i attempt to enact them in order. i just don't know until run-time the exact amount of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a dependency on a certain operation that has to happen afterwards.

For example,

```
let operation = RandomOperation()
let laterOperation = RandomOperation()

laterOperation.addDependency(operation)
```

what it does is the laterOperation waits to start until the previous operation ends its process.

-- it seems that you have an unknown number of operation to take care of. 
I recommend you make a custom class of "group operation".

And all the custom class does is to have a queue which is OperationQueue
and variable operations.

at the end, you add operations to queue by

```
queue.addOperation(operations:waitUntilFinished:)
```

Comment: in your example you have to know at compile time that `operation` and `lastOperation` exist - but i don't know until runtime what instances there are, because the amount is unknown. so how can i `addDependency` between them property?

Comment: Does that mean you have at least two arrays of operations, which one depends on the other but you don't know the number of operations in each array until runtime? It's a bit hard to grasp what's going on. Can you share this part of your code so I can take a look?

Comment: If you want to avoid using dependencies then you can set the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` property of the operation queue to 1 which then means that only one operation can run at a time effectively making it a synchronous asynchronous queue.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive function:

```
func removeAllEggs(eggIDs: [String], completion:@escaping () -> ()) {
    var ids = eggIDs
    let id = ids.last

    Alamofire.request(endpoint, method: .post, parameters: parametes, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseData { response in

        // check response etc...

        if ids.count > 1 {
            ids.removeLast()
            removeAllEggs(eggIDs: ids, completion: completion)
        } else {
            // you just sent the last item
            return completion()
        }
    }
}
```

and to use it:

```
func callItHere() {
    removeAllEggs(eggIDs: allEggs) {
        // Done! poof! all gone!
    }
}
```